# creating geotiff in ArcGIS to publish in geoserver

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, arcgis-9.3, geotiff-tiff

How can I create a geotiff image (to publish using Geoserver)?

I want to publish geo-reference image in geoserver.Then i chose image format as geotiff and create using arcGIS 9.3.It create tiff,tfw and aux files.But when publish using geoserver it gives this message,

"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: GeoTIFF"

What is the error,I think this is not the correct method to create geotiff(to using GS).True?
If answer is yes  What is the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.It is simple.
Use qGIS to create geotiff.Then it works fine for me.